# how can i make my bootstrap code responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I got this task using bootstrap [my task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05WwP.png)

that's my code that I tried:

https://snipboard.io/aA8pfb.jpg

```
<body>    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="height: 300px">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-8 h2 bg-primary">1</div>
            <div class="mid w-50">
                <div class="row ml-0 pb-2" style="height: 150px">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 h2 bg-success">2</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 h2 bg-danger">3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row ml-0" style="height: 150px">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 h2 bg-warning">4</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 h2 bg-secondary">5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and it didn't work that's the result I got using this code:
https://snipboard.io/YVRg84.jpg

What did I do wrong? How can I make it responsive like this picture? And why do my code got space that I can't get rid of between the two rows?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 300px">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 h2 bg-primary">1</div>
        <div class="mid w-50 col-12 col-lg-6 ">
            <div class="row ml-0 pb-2" style="height: 150px">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 h2 bg-success">2</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 h2 bg-danger">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row ml-0" style="height: 150px">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 h2 bg-warning">4</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 h2 bg-secondary">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

also to remove spacing you probably are using height incorrectly please inspect your code in the browser and experiment with the heights of the div , it will fix your spacing problem .